# In an ergodic DTMC, what is the expectation and variance of number of visits to a state up to certain time

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

Let $P=\{p_{ij}\}$ be the transition matrix of an ergodic DTMC (say finite states for simplicity), let $p^{(k)}_{ij}$ be the entries of $P^k$.

If the associated Markov chain is initially at some state $i$ (i.e., $X_0=i$), and $V_n^{(j)}$ is the number of visits to some state $j$ (may not be $i$) up to time $n$, then it is true that
$$
E[V_n^{j}|X_0=i]=\sum_{k=1}^np^{(k)}_{ij}.
$$
[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032496/expected-number-of-visits-to-a-state-of-a-markov-chain-up-to-a-certain-time) has a related proof.

Also, is there any way to find the variance of $V_n^{j}|X_0=i$ using $P$ and (k-steps) transition matrices $P^k$, i.e,
$$
Var[V_n^{j}|X_0=i] = ?
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't this just writing $V_n^j=\sum_{k=1}^n 1(X_k=j)$ and then distributing the conditional expectation over the sum?

Comment: Yes, and you can square Ian's equation and take expectations to get the second moment (and hence variance).

Comment: @Michael By squaring Ian's equation there are some cross terms $1(X_k=j)1(X_l=j)$ for $0\leq k,l \leq n$. I've been trying to work out these terms using $P$ and $P_k$ (preferably can express the solution in matrix notation at the end). Do you have any suggestion about how the solution may look like?

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your help! Any hint on the variance expression?

Comment: @BenFung Formally it's easy: $\operatorname{Var}(V_n^j)=E[(V_n^j)^2]-E[V_n^j]^2=E \left [ \left ( \sum_{k=1}^n 1(X_k=j) \right )^2 \right ] - \left ( \sum_{k=1}^n P(X_k=j) \right )^2$. Actually calculating this is a bit more difficult. In particular, the first term involves cross terms of the form $P(X_k=j \text{ and } X_r=j)$. These can be handled by conditioning: supposing $k<r$, $P(X_k=j \text{ and } X_r=j)=P(X_k=j) P(X_r=j \mid X_k=j)=P(X_k=j) p^{(r-k)}_{jj}$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks again for your hint! I will try to work the details out!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\1}{\mathbb{I}}$Let us call $\1$ the indicator function, i.e., $$\1_A(\omega) = \begin{cases}1, & \omega \in A\\ 0, & \omega \notin A.\end{cases}$$
Then we use two well-known facts, $$E(\1_A) = P(A), \, \text{Var}(\1_A) = P(A)(1-P(A)). \tag{1}$$ Now, we know that the number of visits is simply the sum of indicator functions, that is $$V_n^j = \sum_{k=0}^n\1_{X_k = j}. \tag{2}$$ Note, I took the sum from $0$ to $n$, but from the question, it is possible you want to take it to be $1$ to $n$. 
Now, taking expectations, we see that 
$$\begin{align}
E(V_n^j) &= E\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\1_{X_k = j}\right) \tag{by (2)}\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^nE(\1_{X_k = j}) \tag{by linearity} \\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^nP(X_k = j). \tag{by (1)}
\end{align}$$
To get the variances, we just use the other identity in $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give a little more detail on the variance? The indicator variables seem to be correlated. What do the covariance terms look like?

Comment: Yes, you can use $\text{Cov}(\mathbb{I}_A,\mathbb{I}_B) = P(A,B)-P(A)P(B) = P(A|B)P(B)-P(A)P(B)$

Comment: @BenFung : I am curious:  How is it that you needed this answer, given Ian's much earlier comment? (which I gave the single thumbs up on).